# Prima multiples database

Tags: node.js, prisma

I have a system that I modeled 1 database per customer.

Today I control the database version manually, but I want to use Prisma to for that, for someone how do I run my migrations and multiple databases at the same time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create multiple `PrismaClients`, one for each of your customers.

Here's a Feature Request on supporting [Multiple Databases](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2443). There are various ways suggested in the Feature Request which would allow you to use multiple databases with Prisma.